# Adding data only in last column of a row and keeping preceeding cells empty

Tags: html, html-table

Here is what I have done to make a calendar. How can I do it other way if possible without having these empty `<td>` tags because when I apply hover CSS to data cells empty cells too get showed and behave like non-empty data cells.

```
 <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Can you add your code on [http://jsfiddle.net/]?

Comment: Unclear what you are saying. Can you create be more specific or create [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colspan` like this

```
<tr>
     <td colspan="7">1</td>
</tr>
```

This will create a single `<td>` with width equal to 7`<td>`s

The syntax is

```
<td colspan="number">
```

where number specifies the number of columns a cell should span.

Read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

**UPDATE**

If you need to set 1 just for sunday, then you'll have to do it like this

```
<tr>
     <td colspan="6">1</td>
     <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I am using this for making a calendar so I want '1' to be present under 'sunday', I hope u got my point.